# Rails 5.1 app freezing on heroku deploy with Yarn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, yarnpkg, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm deploying my first Rails 5.1 app to Heroku just now and seem to be coming up against a brick wall with Yarn.

When I try to deploy, it freezes at the same stage each time. It will do this for 30minutes or longer, by which point I get bored and start again.

All I have in my package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "MusicApp",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "fontawesome": "^4.7.2",
    "semantic-ui": "^2.2.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Full deploy log is below:

```
-----> Deleting 0 files matching .slugignore patterns.
 !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
            Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.4.0
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.13.7
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.7) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.15.0). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
       Installing i18n 0.8.1
       Installing rake 12.0.0
       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
       Installing minitest 5.10.2
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
       Installing erubi 1.6.0
       Installing builder 3.2.3
       Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
       Installing nio4r 2.1.0 with native extensions
       Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.2
       Installing rack 2.0.3
       Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
       Installing arel 8.0.0
       Installing aws-sigv4 1.0.0
       Installing jmespath 1.3.1
       Installing bcrypt 3.1.11 with native extensions
       Installing multi_json 1.12.1
       Installing json 2.0.4 with native extensions
       Installing mimemagic 0.3.2
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Installing execjs 2.7.0
       Installing method_source 0.8.2
       Installing thor 0.19.4
       Installing ffi 1.9.18 with native extensions
       Installing sass 3.4.24
       Installing mini_magick 4.7.0
       Installing pg 0.20.0 with native extensions
       Installing puma 3.8.2 with native extensions
       Using bundler 1.13.7
       Installing tilt 2.0.7
       Installing temple 0.7.7
       Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.3
       Installing aasm 4.12.0
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.3
       Installing nokogiri 1.7.2 with native extensions
       Installing websocket-driver 0.6.5 with native extensions
       Installing mime-types 3.1
       Installing rack-test 0.6.3
       Installing sprockets 3.7.1
       Installing aws-sdk-core 2.9.7
       Installing blitline 2.8.0
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing uglifier 3.2.0
       Installing figaro 1.1.1
       Installing font-awesome-sass 4.7.0
       Installing sassc 1.11.2 with native extensions
       Installing slim 3.0.7
       Installing turbolinks 5.0.1
       Installing activesupport 5.1.1
       Installing aws-sdk-resources 2.9.7
       Installing mail 2.6.5
       Installing loofah 2.0.3
       Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Installing globalid 0.4.0
       Installing activemodel 5.1.1
       Installing delayed_job 4.1.3
       Installing aws-sdk 2.9.7
       Installing jbuilder 2.6.4
       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
       Installing activejob 5.1.1
       Installing carrierwave 0.11.2
       Installing activerecord 5.1.1
       Installing actionview 5.1.1
       Installing carrierwave-aws 1.1.0
       Installing actionpack 5.1.1
       Installing delayed_job_active_record 4.1.2
       Installing actioncable 5.1.1
       Installing actionmailer 5.1.1
       Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.0
       Installing railties 5.1.1
       Installing coffee-rails 4.2.2
       Installing jquery-rails 4.3.1
       Installing rails 5.1.1
       Installing sass-rails 5.0.6
       Installing webpacker 2.0
       Installing slim-rails 3.1.2
       Installing sassc-rails 1.3.0
       Bundle complete! 38 Gemfile dependencies, 77 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Bundle completed (128.26s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.7) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.15.0). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
-----> Installing node-v6.10.0-linux-x64
-----> Installing yarn-0.22.0
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       yarn install v0.22.0
       [1/5] Resolving packages...
       [2/5] Fetching packages...
       warning fsevents@1.1.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.1.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/5] Linking dependencies...
       [4/5] Building fresh packages...
```

Anybody else have this same problem?

Comment: It is must better to precompile your js, css locally. Heroku is slow in this.

Comment: Why would heroku be slow? It's still using sprockets, just like a typical Rails setup

Comment: If you are on small dyno, it has only 512MB ram which not enough for assets compilation process-- a lot of swap happens and the process is painful.

Comment: I would contact Heroku. Rails 5.1 + Yarn is a relatively new setup. I'm sure Heroku would appreciate being notified of issues so they can continue to improve the process.